# Pandas pivot table re-indexing lose margins?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table, reindex

I've been exploring with pandas pivot table when I came across 2 questions.

Say I now have a pivot table like this:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='age', index='Name', columns=['Domestic?', 'Size'], margins=True)
Output:
    Domestic?  Y               N 
    Size     Large Small     Large Small  All
Name         
Tiger          10    NA        5     1     16
Dog             5     1        3     1     10
Cat             6     2        4     1     13
All            21     3        12    3     39
```

But what I really want is:

```
     Domestic?  Y                   N 
     Size     Large Small Medium    Large Small Medium All
Name         
Tiger          10    NA     NA     5     1        NA    16
Dog             5     1     NA     3     1        NA    10
Cat             6     2     NA     4     1        NA    13
All            21     3     NA     12    3        NA    39
```

So I tried to add a new category in 'Size' by reindexing:

```
 size_list = ['Large', 'Small', 'Medium']
 pd.reindex(size_list, level=1, axis=1)
```

Here is what I get:

```
 Output:
      Domestic?  Y               N 
      Size     Large Small     Large Small  
  Name         
  Tiger          10    NA        5     1     
  Dog             5     1        3     1     
  Cat             6     2        4     1     
  All            21     3        12    3
```

2 problems occur:

1. why is Medium not added to the table?
2. why is margin on the left dropped?

Can somebody help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: @sharmajee499 sorry the data I'm dealing with is confidential... So I just plainly made them up